# im having a Syntax Error

Tags: python, syntax-error

So I'm using python-2 and I don't know whats wrong with this line? It looks perfect to me?

this is the whole command:

```
if used_prefix and (cmd=="yp" or cmd=="bal" or cmd=="money" or cmd=="balance") and user.name in whitelist:
        if user.name in yoko:
            room.message(user.name.capitalize()+' your balance is '+yokopoints)
        else:
            room.message(acthelp)
```

this is the error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
stephen@crunchbang:~$ python ~/downloads/inhaley/inhaley.py
  File "/home/stephen/downloads/inhaley/inhaley.py", line 755

if used_prefix and (cmd=="yp" or cmd=="bal" or cmd=="money" or cmd=="balance") and user.name in whitelist:
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: The error says you have a problem with your indentation... reindent your code...

Comment: I'd recommend you to use spaces to indent. Check you have not mixed tabs and spaces because that may give troubles.

Comment: You can use "PyCharm 3.4 IDE" for python ... This will help you for better code assistance and analysis.

Comment: You're showing *two* errors here, only one of them can have occurred during a single run. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by mixing tabs and spaces. That causes problems because your editor's tab width can be different to Python's. Check for this by running Python with the `-tt` argument, which will explicitly check for and error on the mixed indentation, instead of waiting until the parser gets confused. This is the default in Python 3.

The way to avoid this problem is to choose *either* tabs or spaces to indent, and configure your editor accordingly. Once it is properly configured, hitting the `Tab` key will always insert the appropriate character(s) (either one tab character, or several spaces - 4 is typical for Python code). You may need to check your editor's documentation if there isn't an obvious way to change that setting.